# Add class to li item of element currently in view

Tags: jquery

I have smooth scrolling to element. Active class is added to selected li. Everything is working fine until i scroll down with mouse, than active class is not adding to current element li.

I am using:

```
<ul class="features">
<li class="active"><a href="#block1">block 1</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#block2">block 2</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#block3">block 3</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="#block4">block 4</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="block1">my content....</div>
<div id="block2">my content....</div>
<div id="block3">my content....</div>
<div id="block4">my content....</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.menu-features li > a').click(function() {
$('.menu-features li').removeClass();
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
});

$('a[href^="#"]').click(function() {
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top-120}, 700);
return false;
e.preventDefault();
});
```

I tried to use [waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin to detect element in view, but how to mark li with the same id as blocks id?

i used:

```
$('#block3').waypoint(function(direction) {
    $('.menu-features li').addClass('test')
});
```

but it adds test class to all li elements, but not for current in view.

Answer (score 0):

Try $(this).find('.menu-features li').addClass('test');

Comment: hmm, but need to add class or id only to li with the same id as divs to which we scrolled , for example if i scroll to div with id block3, than jquery function must add class only to li a.block3 Sorry for my english :)